# I created a tag, edited a basic description, appears it was approved, but the description doesn't appear yet

Tags: support, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I created a bch-code tag, since there was a question specific to bch-codes. I edited it to include a basic description. Then in a second edit, I added a wikipedia link about bch codes, so it could be approved or disapproved separately. It appears the initial edit with the basic description was approved, but the description doesn't appear yet. Link to the edit review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23638401

Comment: Both are pending approval https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23638400, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23638401

Comment: There shouldn't be any summary in the tag popup, as there is no excerpt yet. You are probably seeing your pending edit.

Comment: @SamuelLiew - I see one "approve", was that for something else (perhaps just the creation of the tag)? I've since revised the tag info to match what i see for Reed Solomon tag. Should be OK now, and I'll just wait for the review. Thanks for the tag edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edits are both pending - you're seeing the edit because you made it, but when anyone else goes to the tag page:

> [image: [tag:bch-code]]

Each of your edits needs approvals from two users with more than 5000 reputation - or, if you have 20,000 or more, they don't need approval (similar to 2000 for other edits). All edits that require approval will appear to the user that made them, but not to any other user.

Comment: Thanks, what I didn't know is that it took two approvals.

Comment: Yeah - it's similar to a normal edit suggestion in a lot of ways.